# Infinispan library mode replicated TreeCache removeNode throws "ISPN000456: Cache does not contain the atomic map"

Tags: infinispan

I am using Infinispan 9.2.5.Final library with Jgroups in my distributed service thats running on Kubernetes.

I know I have data in the replicated TreeCache of my distributed application in location "/live/policy" since the application is able to read from it. The application is able to perform writes in other locations of the cache like "/temp". However when it is time to remove a node as shown below it has suddenly begun throwing the exception also shown below.

This piece of code has worked in the past is working in other environments as well today. So it looks like the cache got corrupted for some unknown reason in this environment. I am trying to find out what this error means, whether there is any way to come out of it, and try to find the cause. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Unfortunately this is not reproducible anywhere else and I dont have access to make custom cache operations since this is in production.

```
configsCacheInUse.removeNode("/live/policy");
```

Throws exception:

```
InvocationContextInterceptor: ISPN000136: Error executing command VersionedPrepareCommand, writing keys [NodeKey{
```

STRUCTURE, fqn=/live}, NodeKey{DATA, fqn=/live/policy}, NodeKey{STRUCTURE, fqn=/live/policy}]
org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217....

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ISPN000456: Cache does not contain the atomic map.
        at org.infinispan.atomic.impl.AtomicMapProxyImpl.mapDoesNotExist(AtomicMapProxyImpl.java:106)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
        at org.infinispan.atomic.impl.AtomicMapProxyImpl.getMap(AtomicMapProxyImpl.java:110)
        at org.infinispan.atomic.impl.AtomicMapProxyImpl.access$700(AtomicMapProxyImpl.java:56)
        at org.infinispan.atomic.impl.AtomicMapProxyImpl$Clear.apply(AtomicMapProxyImpl.java:341)
        at org.infinispan.atomic.impl.AtomicMapProxyImpl$Clear.apply(AtomicMapProxyImpl.java:332)
        at org.infinispan.commands.functional.ReadWriteKeyCommand.perform(ReadWriteKeyCommand.java:100)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CallInterceptor.visitCommand(CallInterceptor.java:29)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextThenApply(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.TxDistributionInterceptor.handleTxFunctionalCommand(TxDistributionInterceptor.java:517)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.TxDistributionInterceptor.visitReadWriteKeyCommand(TxDistributionInterceptor.java:188)
        at org.infinispan.commands.functional.ReadWriteKeyCommand.acceptVisitor(ReadWriteKeyCommand.java:110)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor$EntryWrappingVisitor.handleWriteCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:773)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor$EntryWrappingVisitor.visitReadWriteKeyCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:743)
        at org.infinispan.commands.functional.ReadWriteKeyCommand.acceptVisitor(ReadWriteKeyCommand.java:110)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.applyModificationsAndThen(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:830)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.wrapEntriesForPrepareAndApply(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:816)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.VersionedEntryWrappingInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(VersionedEntryWrappingInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:185)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.NotificationInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(NotificationInterceptor.java:39)
        at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:185)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lambda$new$0(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:34)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationSuccessFunction.apply(InvocationSuccessFunction.java:21)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.SyncInvocationStage.addCallback(SyncInvocationStage.java:42)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationStage.thenApply(InvocationStage.java:24)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:185)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndHandle(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:183)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.TxInterceptor.handlePrepareCommand(TxInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.TxInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(TxInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:185)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.lambda$new$0(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationSuccessFunction.apply(InvocationSuccessFunction.java:21)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.addCallback(SimpleAsyncInvocationStage.java:69)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationStage.thenApply(InvocationStage.java:24)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.asyncInvokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:224)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.visitCommand(TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndHandle(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:185)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTxCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:203)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:69)`

Comment: Tree cache module is legacy. It was only developed as a bridge for users coming from JBoss Cache 9 years ago. It's no longer maintained and we encourage people to move to the key/value pair Cache API, or if needed more complex object layouts, use Hibernate OGM.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like restarting all the pods of my service may have fixed this. Most likely the stale lock was removed upon restart and replication succeeded.